# Reason: non-integer powers of Hermitian matrix not Hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, power-series, symmetry

Let $\alpha = 2.1$.
If $A$ is symmetric real, $A^\alpha$ remains symmetric (although it could be complex-valued).  If $B$ is Hermitian, $B^\alpha$ isn't Hermitian (losses the symmetry).

However, for integer powers e.g. when $\alpha=3$, $B^\alpha$ remains Hermitian.

May I know why the non-integer powers of Hermitian matrices behave this way?

*PS: I computed the powers with the eigen decomposition approach.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Hermitian matrix $B$ has eigendecomposition
$$
B=U\Lambda U^{*}
$$
where $U$ is unitary and $\Lambda = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$ has only real-valued entries.
By *eigendecomposition approach*, I assume you mean that you are defining
$$
B^{\alpha}\equiv U\Lambda^{\alpha}U^{*}.
$$

> **Lemma**. Let $\alpha$ be a real number and $B$ be a Hermitian matrix.
>   Then, $B^{\alpha}$ is **not** Hermitian if and only if one of the eigenvalues of $B$ is negative **and** $\alpha$ is **not** an integer.

*Proof*. $B^{\alpha}$ being Hermitian is equivalent to $\Lambda^{\alpha}$ being real since
$$
(B^{\alpha})^{*}
=U\Lambda^{\alpha}U^{*}
=U(\Lambda^{\alpha})^{*}U^{*}.
$$
The result follows from noting that for a real number $\lambda$, $\lambda^{\alpha}$ is not real if and only if $\lambda$ is negative and $\alpha$ is not an integer.